# regarding data retrieve in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote this hibernate program in MyEclipse IDE.I want to retrieve the data from student table and display in console,i want to retrieve the row whose primary key value is 2(as i entered in the table in database) 
I am getting following exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: 
java.lang.Integer

program:

```
package info.inetsolv;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibJavaPrgm {
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
 cfg.configure();
 SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
 Session hsession = sf.openSession();
 Transaction ts = hsession.beginTransaction();

 Student stu=new Student();

 hsession.load(2,stu);

 ts.commit();
 hsession.close();
 sf.close();
}

}
```

Comment: And What does your _Student_ model class and table looks like.

Comment: student table consist of 3 column(id,name,address).i just want to retrieve one row and display to console

Answer (score 2):

There are two [Session.load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) methods that you can use:

> load(Class theClass, Serializable id)
>
> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming that the instance exists.

and

> load(Object object, Serializable id)
>
> Read the persistent state associated with the given identifier into the given transient instance.

None of these methods take the ID as first argument.

You want

```
Student student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 2);
```

or

```
Student student = new Student();
session.load(student, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Student stu=new Student();

hsession.load(2,stu);
```

It should be:

```
Student stu = (Student) hsession.load(Student.class, 2);
```

Comment: @Surya: your program doesn't output anything to the console. add `System.out.println(student.getName());`.

Comment: Student stu = (Student) hsession.load(Student.class, 2);                System.out.println(stu.getName());------>using this i can retrieve data of one row.If i want to retrieve all the data of that table then which load() method to use?